# Kanban board written in Python

Tags: open-source, web-apps, python, project-management, self-hosted

I'm looking for [kanban board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board) similar to [Kanboard](https://kanboard.net/) but written in Python, in particular:

- kanban board, with configurable lanes
- web app
- installable on premise (no cloud, no hosted on internet only)
- open source
- friendly/tolerable license (no Affero GPL), like MIT or Apache

Nice to have:

- extensible with plugins

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try looking at [Kanbanara](http://www.kanbanara.com). It is an open source web-based Project Management System using the kanban methodology which you can download and host yourself.

Comment: Please show your affiliation to to www.kanbanara.com

Comment: Thank you very much, but the license is AGPL and so unacceptable for my organization.